# How do I disable a button in react hooks that has a setState function already inside the onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to disable a like button that already has an useState for incrementing the likes. And I wanted to disable the button once its clicked.
I would appreciate some help. Thank You!

````
const allItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "The Rise and Decline of Patriarchal Systems",
    image: "https://img.thriftbooks.com/api/images/i/m/8ECA8C9BAF351D13622ADFFBFA8A5D4E2BAABAFF.jpg",
    likes: 3359,
    price: 1
  }
]

const Shop = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState({allItems, disable: false})

  const updateLike = (item) =>   setItems(items.map(indItem => {
      if (indItem !== item) {
        return indItem
      } 
      else {
        return {...item, likes: item.likes + 1}
      }
    
  }))

  const listItemsToBuy = () => items.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id} className="card"></div>
      <div className="font-text"><h2>{`${item.name}`}</h2>
    </div>
      <h2>Likes: {item.likes}</h2>
      <div>
      <button items={items} onClick={()=> updateLike(item, true)}> Like </button>
  ));```
````

Comment: you can do `<button disabled={item.likes > 0} ......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside updateLike function update your state

`setItems(prevState => { ...prevState, disable: true, })`

Then your button will be look like

```
<button disabled={items.disabled} >
```

But preferable to have separate state for this purpose

Comment: I appreciate your help! I made it work by creating a separate state as you recommended. Thank you!

Comment: Could you also accept this answer as right one?:) I would also appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I did! But it seems that stackoverflow cast a vote if I have 15 reputation. ( I am pretty new at stackoverflow at the moment)

Comment: Actually, you can. Icon below arrow down. I'm new here like you, but can vote. But never mind :)

Comment: Just did! I appreciate your help!